# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30) when accessing CoreData SharedData.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, exc-bad-access

I recently upgraded to Xcode 11.2.1 and in the newest iOS 13.2.2 and am now getting the error

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30)

The line that is erroring is called about 2000 times from a forEach loop.

If I set a breakpoint on the erroring line and run the code in debug mood, the crash doesn't occur

If I add in a print `print("Hi mom")` before the erroring statement, the error doesn't occur

I pretty sure that adding a print statement is just bypassing the actual error and may occur later or in different iOS setups or at lower frequencies.

```
        else if actionFigureSpecificsCoreData != nil {
            coreDataUpdateDate = self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate! as Date

            // WARNING:  Not saving here intentionally as no actual changes are being made - see save functions
            // WARNING:  dont create the iCloud record at this point otherwise the save context may error for null values create the record

            // if the coreData record exists without all defaults and the iCloud record doesn't exist, create the iCloud record.
            // case where device was off-line
            if self.isActionFigureSpecificsCoreDataDefaultValues() == false {
                //                                #if DEBUG
                //                                    print("No iCloud record for Saving from non-default coreData \(self.actionFigureSpecificsGlobalUniqueId) on \(kActionFigureSpecificsRecord)")
                //                                #endif
                isCloudSaveNeeded = true
                shouldSetCloudDataToCore = true
            }
        }
        // if both core data and cloud are nil, set the core data record
        else {

<<<<<<<<-------------crashes on the next line unless I add in a print statement ----------------->>>>>>>

            self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData = ActionFigureSpecificsCoreData(context: SharedData.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext!)
            self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.actionFigureRecordName = self.actionFigureGlobalUniqueId

            // want it and have it are set to defaults by core data
            self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate = NSDate() as Date

            // all other values are set to the database defaults
        }
```

```
class SharedData {

    // core data
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate!
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    // in app purchases
    var isRemoveAdInAppPurchase: Bool = false

    class var sharedInstance: SharedData {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = SharedData()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }

    init() {

        // set core data database properties
        //self.appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        self.appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        self.managedObjectContext = self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
```

top of the crash log from apple

````
{"app_name":"My Toy Chest","timestamp":"2019-11-13 07:18:28.55 -0800","app_version":"6.037","slice_uuid":"6ae4b8f2-ac29-3b31-87a8-3ebf4634251f","adam_id":1217665205,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"com.LightningBrainGames.My-Toy-Chest","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.2.2 (17B102)","incident_id":"41DB21DA-774E-42C1-B340-425689BBCB6A","name":"My Toy Chest"}
Incident Identifier: 41DB21DA-774E-42C1-B340-425689BBCB6A
CrashReporter Key:   43b464acde1fb0315e3dc82db0fb5a581b250135
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             My Toy Chest [478]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5E9921A8-1895-4880-864B-F1D2A0DCDE3B/My Toy Chest.app/My Toy Chest
Identifier:          com.LightningBrainGames.My-Toy-Chest
Version:             1 (6.037)
AppStoreTools:       11B48b
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.LightningBrainGames.My-Toy-Chest [590]


Date/Time:           2019-11-13 07:18:28.0713 -0800
Launch Time:         2019-11-13 07:18:18.5049 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.2.2 (17B102)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cf8fec4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ceab774 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018cdff844 abort + 100
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018ce98b80 _malloc_put + 0
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018ce98df4 malloc_zone_error + 100
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018ce84044 szone_free + 452
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1bd468 __CFBasicHashDrain + 420
7   CoreData                        0x0000000191a475ec -[NSManagedObjectContext+ 71148 (_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 832
8   CoreData                        0x0000000191b746d0 _performRunLoopAction + 368
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d114c2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d10fb18 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1100e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d10f8a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
13  GraphicsServices                0x0000000197067328 GSEventRunModal + 104
14  UIKitCore                       0x0000000191200740 UIApplicationMain + 1936
15  My Toy Chest                    0x00000001001f95e4 0x1001f4000 + 21988
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018cf9a360 start + 4```
````

Comment: It sounds like you might have a race condition of some sort. Print statements are pretty pokey speed wise and it might slow it down just enough to make the condition go away. I'd look into that. This is a bit of a PITA, be a great way to debug stuff like that might be with `os_signpost`. Here's a video from WWDC going over it. I've used it to debug some hard-to-find issues. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/405/

Comment: Looking at your code again, your singleton declaration could be simplified a bit. Here's a cool post on that: https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

Comment: Adrian - I updated the code to `static let sharedInstance = SharedData()`.  I did use private init() for SharedData based on a comment from your link.  I still get the same error. I added a save context within each record set and then started receiving `error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)`

Comment: Cool. I didn't think the declaration of your shared instance was the issue, it was just a little verbose. `libsystem_malloc.dylib malloc_zone_error + 100` is the rabbit hole I'd go down. This link isn't a solution, but it does give some potentially useful things to try to debug your issue: https://github.com/the-blue-alliance/the-blue-alliance-ios/issues/589